# Persistência de coordenadas em banco MySql utilizando Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, .net-core, geolocalização

Estou tendo problema para realizar um select eficiente com relação a coordenadas de geolocalização no MySQl. No banco estou salvando dois valores referentes a latitude e longitude, por tanto quando realizo o Select os dois valores são considerados no Where, porém precisava que fosse interpretados como um só.

Vi que o MySql aceita dados tipo Spatial Data, mas o EF não conversa com este dado.

Essa é a classe que representa o dado a ser salvo

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Nomadwork.Infra.Data.ObjectData
{
    [Table("Address")]
    public class AddressModelData : AEntity
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
        public string Street { get; set; }


        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Number { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
        public string Coutry { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
        public string State { get; set; }


        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(12,9)")]
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }


        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(12,9)")]
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Este é o Select

```cs
public IEnumerable<EstablishmentModelData> GetByLocation(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
            => _context.Establishments
                       .Include(x => x.Address)
                       .Where(establismment
                => (decimal.Round(establismment.Address.Latitude, 3).Equals(decimal.Round(latitude, 3))
                    || decimal.Round(establismment.Address.Longitude, 3).Equals(decimal.Round(longitude, 3)))
                     && establismment.Active)
                    .ToHashSet()
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```

A solução neste caso foi arredondar os valores diminuindo a precisão das coordenadas fornecidas para comparar com as coordenadas armazenadas para que pudesse retornar os endereços próximos.

Agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução temporária foi adicionar mais duas propriedades com valores arredondados com menos precisão: segue código a baixo
Classe

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Nomadwork.Infra.Data.ObjectData
{
    [Table("Address")]
    public class AddressModelData : AEntity
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
        public string Street { get; set; }


        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(10)")]
        public string Number { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
        public string Coutry { get; set; }


        [ Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
        public string State { get; set; }


        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(12,9)")]
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }


        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(12,9)")]
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

        // Propriedade Latitude com menor precisão
        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(4,2)")]
        public decimal LatitudePrecision { get; set; }

        // Propriedade Longitude com menor precisão
        [Required, Column(TypeName = "decimal(4,2)")]
        public decimal LongitudePricision { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Select

```cs
 public IEnumerable<EstablishmmentModelData> GetByLocation(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
            => _context.Establishments
                       .Include(x => x.Address)
                       .Where(establismment
                => (establismment.Address.LatitudePrecision.Equals(decimal.Round(latitude, 2))
                    && establismment.Address.LongitudePricision.Equals(decimal.Round(longitude, 2)))
                     && establismment.Active)
                    .ToHashSet()
                    .Take(20)
                    .ToList();
```